# how to install react on command prompt using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 4s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.


npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 4s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

The create-react-app docs suggest uninstalling the package if it is installed using npm install -g create-react-app, and instead using npx.
Try running the command
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Then create a new react app using
`npx create-react-app app-name-here`

Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/